# org-agenda-sorting-strategy reset after restart

Tags: org-mode

This variable always returns to default value. I tried to 'erase configuration' & remove it from myinit.el.
Have this in myinit.org:

```
(setq org-agenda-sorting-strategy (quote ((todo todo-state-up))))
```

Comment: You have lisp code in an org file? How is that supposed to influence what emacs does? Are you producing your init file by tangling the org file? How do you make emacs use `myinit.el` as its initialization file? What does `myinit.el` look like? In short, I have at least a dozen questions about what you are doing that are not described in your question.

Comment: This is my /.emacs.d https://github.com/slk500/emacs.d I see this line (setq org-agenda-sorting-strategy (quote ((todo todo-state-up)))) in myinit.el

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem depends on how your emacs is deciding what it is using for initialization. We need more information to know that, but we can offer potential causes.

For example, looking at the `init.el` that you have listed in the comments, are you sure that the custom variables block isn't causing your settings for todo to be overwritten?

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
[...]
 '(org-agenda-sorting-strategy
   '((agenda habit-down time-up priority-down category-keep)
     (todo priority-down category-keep)
     (tags priority-down category-keep)
     (search category-keep)))
)
```